# Filter array of objects with arrays nested by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter down results from a large array of objects. Basically I have an input and I want to filter down the results when the input matches one or part of the keywords.

```
export default [
    {
       "id":1014,
       "item":19021,
       "name":"name 1",
       "description":"",
       "image":"http://images.jpg",
       "keywords":[
          "Cake",
          "Party",
          "Birthday"
       ],
    },
    {
       "id":1015,
       "item":19023,
       "name":"name 22",
       "description":"",
       "image":"http://images.jpg",
       "keywords":[
          "NHL",
          "Party"
       ],
    },
    {
       "id":1042,
       "item":19011,
       "name":"name 3",
       "description":null,
       "image":"http://images.jpg",
       "keywords":[
          "Florida Panthers",
          "NHL"
       ],
    },
```

Expected result if input is 'NHL':

```
    {
       "id":1015,
       "item":19023,
       "name":"name 20",
       "description":"",
       "image":"http://images.jpg",
       "keywords":[
          "NHL",
          "Party"
       ],
    },
    {
       "id":1042,
       "item":19011,
       "name":"NHL® Florida Panthers® Slap Shot Cake",
       "description":null,
       "image":"http://images.jpg",
       "keywords":[
          "Florida Panthers",
          "NHL"
       ],
    }
```

I tried something like this:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.keywords === searchFilter)
```

But it doesn't search through the keyword array.

So basically I need something like this:

```
myArray.filter(x => x.keywords[loop through all indexes] === searchFilter)
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Use `includes` along with filter to check if the item present in the `keywords`:`arr.filter(o=>o.keywords.includes('NHL'))`

Comment: You've got it. You can use array.includes(keyword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the nested array `.includes` the string you're looking for:

```js
const myArray=[{id:1014,item:19021,name:"name 1",description:"",image:"http://images.jpg",keywords:["Cake","Party","Birthday"]},{id:1015,item:19023,name:"name 22",description:"",image:"http://images.jpg",keywords:["NHL","Party"]},{id:1042,item:19011,name:"name 3",description:null,image:"http://images.jpg",keywords:["Florida Panthers","NHL"]}];

const filtered = myArray.filter(item => item.keywords.includes('NHL'));
console.log(filtered);
```